# ArangoDB: Traversal condition on related document

Tags: arangodb

Been stuck for days with this concern, trying to accomplish this:
See the provided picture.
The black is the start vertex. Trying to get:

1: All child parts OUTBOUND (from) the start vertex

2: Condition: The children MUST have the INBOUND edge"types" and the other end a document with a variable set to "true" and of the type "type".

3: When a document of type "part" fails to met up the requirements with INBOUND document of type "type" with a attribute to "true", it stops the expand for that path then and there.

4: The documents who failed isn't included in the result either.

5: Should be compatible with any depths.

6: No subqueries (if possible without).

[Example of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVYTq.jpg)

Comment: Could you explain the vertex types and edge types? If you don't want to give away your model, make an example with animals or plants or something. It's a bit difficult to understand your use case. What are your vertex's, edge's, and give some example properties.

Comment: Hi and thx for you reply. I think the easiet way is to see the picture after clicking the link in "Example of graph", it has the vertex types and edge types and also the directions. "part", "partScrew" etc. And the properties to condition on could be called "allowed": true, on the "types" vertex. Something like that. The main question is to stop the traversal on a condition of a related document to the child. Let me know if its still unclear and I will try to export some json or similar. Thx once again!

Comment: What I can't understand in your diagram is the 'undefined' entries, not sure if they are anomalies, a bad path, or what it means.

The way I think of filtering on AQL traversals is that when you do a FOR v, e, p IN ... traversal, look at the `p` object. You can perform complex queries and manipulation on analysing that path. Use `FILTER` clauses at many times in your traversal, filtering out what is a good path and what isn't. You can even dynamically add keys to vertices and edges and do really whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

With the given information, the data model seems questionable. Why are there `true` and `false` vertices instead of a boolean edge attribute per *partScrew*? Is there a reason why it is modeled like this?

Using this data model, I don't see how this would be possible without subqueries. The traversal down a path can be stopped early with `PRUNE`, but that does not support subqueries. That only leaves `FILTER` for post-filtering as option, but be careful, you need to check all vertices on the path and not just the emitted vertex whether it has an inbound `false` type.

Not sure if it works as expected in all cases, but here is what I came up with and the query result, which looks good to me:

```
LET startScrew = FIRST(FOR doc IN screw LIMIT 1 RETURN doc) // Screw A
FOR v,e,p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND startScrew partScrew
  FILTER (
    FOR v_id IN SHIFT(p.vertices[*]._id) // ignore start vertex
      FOR v2 IN 1..1 INBOUND v_id types
      RETURN v2.value
  ) NONE == false
  RETURN {
    path: CONCAT_SEPARATOR(" -- ", p.vertices[*].value)
  }
```

[image: Annotated graph]

| path |
| --- |
| Screw A -- Part D |
| Screw A -- Part E |
| Screw A -- Part E -- Part F |

Dump with test data: https://gist.github.com/Simran-B/6bd9b154d1d1e2e74638caceff42c44f